# Save email(header and body) as PDF programmatically in Thunderbird using JavaScript

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am trying to save an email as a PDF programmatically in Thunderbird.

I have been able to successfully save the body of the email but I have been unable to include the headers(to, from, date, subject, ect..).

I basically want to get a similar output to File > Print.

Below is what I am working with.

```js
function printEmail() {
  var outputFormat = Components.interfaces.nsIPrintSettings.kOutputFormatPDF;

  var webBrowserPrint = window.content.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor)
    .getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPrint);

  var PSSVC = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/gfx/printsettings-service;1"]
    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrintSettingsService);

  var printSettings = PSSVC.newPrintSettings;
  var printerName = "";
  try {
    printerName = "printer_" + PSSVC.defaultPrinterName.replace(" ", "_", "g");
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }

  printSettings.printToFile = true;
  printSettings.toFileName = completeFilePath;
  printSettings.printSilent = true;
  printSettings.outputFormat = outputFormat;

  webBrowserPrint.print(printSettings, null);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `webBrowserPrint.print` function that you are using is a general purpose one, used for printing all kinds of content. I think that it is being called by a higher-level function. I tried to trace this and here is what I found.

The UI print command implemented in
https://dxr.mozilla.org/thunderbird/source/mail/base/content/messageWindow.js

calls [`PrintEnginePrint()`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/thunderbird/source/mailnews/base/resources/content/msgPrintEngine.js#204) which opens [`msgPrintEngine.xul`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/thunderbird/source/mail/base/content/msgPrintEngine.xul) and fires [`OnLoadPrintEngine()`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/thunderbird/source/mailnews/base/resources/content/msgPrintEngine.js#50).

Deeper inside there is a call to [`DisplayMessageForPrinting`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/thunderbird/source/mailnews/local/src/nsMailboxService.cpp#601) which sets a flag `mPrintingOperation`. As a result, the url being printed gets an extra parameter `&header=print` appended.

I tried to replicate what [`OnLoadPrintEngine()`](https://dxr.mozilla.org/thunderbird/source/mailnews/base/resources/content/msgPrintEngine.js#50) does, modifying the print settings on the way. However, I was not able to get it to work:

```
var webBrowserPrint = window.content.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIInterfaceRequestor).getInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIWebBrowserPrint);
var PSSVC = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/gfx/printsettings-service;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrintSettingsService);
var printEngine = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/messenger/msgPrintEngine;1"].createInstance();
printEngine = printEngine.QueryInterface(Components.interfaces.nsIMsgPrintEngine);
printEngine.setWindow(window);
var printSettings = PSSVC.globalPrintSettings; //Any changes to the settings go here.
printEngine.startPrintOperation(printSettings);
```

However, this only causes my TB window to disappear.